# Proof Regarding "Small" Distances

Tags: real-analysis

Let $x_0$ and $x$ be real numbers, and let $\epsilon$ be a positive real number.
Prove that $|x-x_0|<\epsilon$ if and only if $x\in(x_0-\epsilon,x_0+\epsilon)$.

I know to prove this I would need two proofs:

(i) If $|x-x_0|<\epsilon$, then $x\in(x_0-\epsilon,x_0+\epsilon)$.

(ii) If **$x\in(x_0-\epsilon,x_0+\epsilon)$**, then $|x-x_0|<\epsilon$.

For the first is it sufficient to say:

Assume $|x-x_0|<\epsilon$. This is equivalent to $-\epsilon<x-x_0<\epsilon$. Furthermore this is equivalent to $x_0-\epsilon<x<x_0 + \epsilon$. Thus $x\in(x_0-\epsilon,x_0+\epsilon)$?

I feel like I am overlooking something or doing something invalid. Any assistance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proof is correct, and in fact works for both directions - each individual step works in both directions so the proof as a whole does too.